# How do you unhide an event on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I selected 'hide' for a Facebook event that I did not want to be reminded of, and now I can not even view the even when explicitly trying (it is not listed on the creators page and the page is listed as not found when I click on the link in the original email).  How can I unhide the event?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the event has been deleted. What's the time frame between hiding the event and trying to view it?

Facebook might also have locked you out of viewing the event, depending on its privacy settings. You could have removed it from "My events" instead of hiding it, by accident.

The event is probably not public, judging from its behavior.

> Events have two different privacy options depending on how the admin set up the event:
>
> 1. Public Events: Anyone can add themselves to the guest list without receiving an invitation or being approved by an admin. They can see the event information and all associated content (e.g., photos, Wall posts and videos).
> 2. Private Events: The event cannot be found in searches. These events are by invitation only. **People who have not been invited cannot view the event description, Wall, or photos.** They also will not see any Feed stories about the event.

— [Facebook's Help Center](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=13052) (emphasis mine)

I think the only thing you can do is ask the creator to invite you again.

Comment: It was under a minute.  If I removed it from 'my events' can I get it back?  Seems odd that I can't access from link in original email either.

Comment: Without looking at the specific event in question, I can't say for certain, but the best advice I can give you is to contact the person who invited you and ask them to invite you again. (I'm assuming you were invited, because you said you got an email.) See edit to answer.